# Find if two values belongs a to the same sublist

Tags: python, list

**I dont know how to compare the user and the password for the same account, I only achieved to give acces to the program with any username and any password.** This is the last step to finish my project :(

The list looks like this

```
[["user1", "password1"], ["user2", "password2"], ...]
```

```
users = []
user = input("user: ")
password = input("password: ")
with open("Users and passwords.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for item in lines:
        data = item.split("|")
        users.append(data)
    # Now "users" is a 2D list
    print(users)
```

Comment: It is better to use `lines = file.read().splitlines()` to remove the trailing newline in each line.

Comment: How is this related to tkinter? the tag should be removed.

Comment: Also, with relation to the question, can you elaborate on the format in which the usernames and passwords are stored in the `.txt` file being opened?

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to use a dictionary to keep all users and their passwords, like this:

```py
users={
    "user1" : "password1",
    "user2" : "password2",
}
```

Than you can save the dictionary as a json file

```py
with open(f'{path}/users.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(users, f)
```

Than to find specific user you could easily:

```py
with open(f'{path}/users.json') as json_file:
   users = json.load(json_file)

user = input("user: ")
password = input("password: ")
if users.get(user)==password:
   #success
```